# Python3 проблема при импорте

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

У меня возникла вот эта ошибка: ImportError: cannot import name 'admin' from 'admin.blueprint' после того как я в модуле blueprint.py произвел импорт Post из models.py, помогите мне пожалуйста разобраться со структурой приложения, чтобы избежать в будущем таких ошибок.

**Модуль <main.py>**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from admin.blueprint import admin
from config import Config


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.register_blueprint(admin, url_prefix='/admin')


import views

if __name__ == '__main__'
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Модуль <blueprint.py>**

```
from flask import Blueprint, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
from config import ConfigAdmin
from models import Post

admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')


@admin.route('/')
def admin_login():
    return render_template('admin/admin-login.html')

@admin.route('/admin-panel', methods=['POST'])
def admin_panel():
if request.form['username'] == ConfigAdmin.ADMIN_NAME and request.form['password'] == ConfigAdmin.ADMIN_PASS:
     return render_template('admin/admin-panel.html')
else:
     return redirect(url_for('admin.admin_login'))

@admin.route('/create-post')
def create_post():
    return render_template('admin/create-post.html')

@admin.route('/add-post', methods=['POST'])
def add_post():
if request.method == 'POST':
    body = Post(post_title=request.form['title'], post_text=request.form['article'], post_img=redirect.form['file'])
    db.session.add(body)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
else:
    return "Err"
```

**Модуль <models.py>**

```
from main import db


class Admin(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    passw = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)


class Post(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   title = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
   text = db.Column(db.String(500), unique=True)
   img = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

Ниже на скриншотах ошибка и расположение файлов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В большинстве случаев `import error` возникает из-за того, что код просто не может найти путь к библиотеке / коду, от куда будет производиться импорт. Я думаю, что проблема в том, что `models` и `blueprint` просто находятся в разных папках. Попробуйте проверить, будет ли работать код в единой (папке) ?

Comment: То что models и blueprint — в разных папках, это совершенно ни как не влияет.